# Some values not able to be referenced from the SDK

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ and when I try to reference certain values in the SDK, I am not able to (see below picture)

I've even set the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 19, and rebuilt the project to make sure.

Is this a bug in IntelliJ?

Could someone verify that they are able to access these values in their own projects?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the android platform resources are not public so you can't reference them directly. There are 2 ways to access them.

The not recommended way: use `android:background="@*android:color/primary_text_holo_dark"`

The recommended way: copy the xml, and any dependencies from the android sdk directory into your own project

Comment: Wow, this is really tedious.

Comment: yep, that's because you are not supposed to use them directly in this way since Google can change them at any time. the safe way is to use the provided styles and attributes like `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"`

Comment: I'm just trying to style the navigation drawer the same way the spinner is in the Holo.Light.DarkActionBar theme.  The drawer doesn't seem to inherit the style.

Comment: You can see how it is done at the bottom of this page: 
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html